# how to: open or save a pdf file from inside my html5 based iphone app?

Tags: iphone, html, pdf, file-io

If I just use a standard link the pdf opens but it basically hijacks my app interface and the user can no longer back out of the pdf.   If I make the pdf load into a div then i see gobbeldygook in the div.
I want the link to either save the pdf with a standard *Save As* dialog or open the pdf in a default app - possibly giving the choice of apps is there is no default.

I am using html5 for the iphone.  My app uses its own history for navigation.

PS:  so far I am using a link like so 
`<a id="pdflink" href="http://www.myserverzzz.com/menus/menu_4869_document.pdf" target="_blank">Download PDF</a>` and it seems to work, but I'm worried that maybe this is not optimal, it would be better if I could open the pdf in a div inside my app, like a div below the link  or below a *download pdf* button.

Comment: “save the pdf with a standard Save As dialog” — the standard *iOS* “Save As” dialog?? I don’t think there is one.

Comment: What about an *open with* or *save as* that might appear if safari tries to open the link?  I was thinking of opening the link in a new safari window.  How to do that from within my app?

Comment: again, Safari on *iOS*? Since when does anything on iOS say “Save As”?

Comment: Do you really want to argue about dialogs and labels or can you help address my question?  I'm new to macs and iphones and ios dev so ...

Comment: I’m not trying to argue, I’m just saying I don’t think there is such a thing as a general “Save As” dialog on iOS.

Comment: OK, so I'll go with the link type approach - actualy I'll use an input tag and javascript with window.open so I  can style it up differently - until I find a better way that doesn't involve that flash based approach I saw somewhere.

Comment: I’m *definitely* sure that the Flash-based approach wouldn’t work on iOS :) I think when iOS Safari opens a PDF it provides the user an option to save the PDF in iBooks, but presumably only if they’ve got iBooks installed (iBooks doesn’t ship with iOS if I remember correctly). iOS doesn’t provide the user with direct filesystem access like most desktop OSes do, so there’s no general concept of just saving a file.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I still got a lot to learn on this platform.