# Open external link to a pdf from html5 app - phonegap

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, pdf, external

I'd like to know what I'm doing wrong with this.
Basicaly I'm opening and in the google view some pdf:

```
<a id="pdflink" href="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://pdpdpd.pdf" target="_blank">Pdf</a>
```

But when it opens it and I see the typical tools inside that view, like the magnifier, print, open original, etc.; Well, the print and open original won't work, I have no problems with them in chrome on my computer, however after the instalation on the phone it won't work, the page it'd stay blank doing nothing.

What could it be?

Comment: use inAppBrowser plugin with _system param

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to link a offline website by another website?

if you are trying to link then use a href instead of a id

Comment: Tell me whether it worked or not and please explain your problem more briefly.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7244837/how-to-open-or-save-a-pdf-file-from-inside-my-html5-based-iphone-app but for android and iphone together (phonegap). Not sure I understand what you're saying, there's already a href there.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot download all the file URL which are tagged into href.

1. In this case you need to use [filetransfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) plugin for downloading the file,
2. Use [this plugin](https://github.com/sitewaerts/cordova-plugin-document-viewer) or [this another plugin](https://github.com/cyberkatze/pdfViewer) for viewing PDF file

anyways the URL which you mentioned in your answer is not having proper PDF.

Comment: I know about the plugins, but I wasn't able to make them work, maybe I'll give it a go again later on when I get home. I know it's not a proper URL, I edited it on porpose for this case. As I said, it works on chrome but not on the phone. Anyway, thank you.

Comment: If you can able to open a url in PC browser then you can able to download it from cordova app too. But use plugin

Answer (score 0):

Use File Transfer Plugin to download file.

```
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer 

fileTransfer.download(
    uri,
    fileURL,
    function(entry) {
        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log("download error source " + error.source);
        console.log("download error target " + error.target);
        console.log("upload error code" + error.code);
    }

);
```